# How to route the traffic using the weights among the internal service pods for canary release?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have to route the traffic between the microservices. I have achieved the canary release for exposed micro-service by altering the weights in the virtualservice(Istio). But I am unaware to route the traffic between the non exposed micro-services. How to achieve